# Hibernate Optional Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have a question regarding Hibernate annotated and inheritance.

In the database, I have a `parent` table and a `child` table. The `parent` table has columns which are not replicated in the `child` table (a `joined` relation in Hibernate). For every row in the `child` table, there's a row in the `parent` table. In this case, the row in the `child` table and the corresponding row in the `parent` table has the same `id` value. However, the `parent` table has rows that does not have a corresponding row in the `child` table.

A concrete `child` entity is represented by making a join between the `child` and the `parent`, and a concrete `parent` is simply represented by the table `parent`.

The object-oriented way to represent this is to have the following:

The `parent` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    // More properties
}
```

The `child` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Child extends Parent{
    // More properties
}
```

When I'm listing all the childs using `List child = session.createQuery("FROM Child").list();` everyting goes well. However, my problem is that when I try to list the parents using `List parent = session.createQuery("FROM Parent").list();`, it returns a list of `child` objects.

Is there a way to represent an "optional" inheritance in Hibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you directly lookup the parent entity from a JPA inheritance structure then the "most bottom" sub-entities are determined by the JPA implementation because those ones need to be persisted in the persistent area. Therefore the "optional inheritance" you mention is not possible in JPA.
Please see the answer of [Hibernate Inheritance Strategy and Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530657/hibernate-inheritance-strategy-and-why/1533041#1533041)

In your case the a LEFT OUTER JOIN is always applied. What you can do:

1. You can cast your result to the parent entity because of the inheritance. You will get your intended result but with performance OVERHEAD because of the unnecessary join.
2. Another option is NOT USING the INHERITANCE. Instead of that you can use unidirectional one-to-one relation where the **child** has the foreign key **id** to the **parent**. In this model you can handle the **child** with its **parent** (by using CascadeType.ALL) and also query the **parent** separately without joins. One example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToOneUnidirectional.htm

Answer (score 1):

> The parent table has columns which are not replicated in the child table (a joined relation in Hibernate)

If the child table is supposed to be a subclass of the parent table, then does this really make sense to you? The sub class should have everything in the super class and possibly more.

What I think you really want to model is something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    // More properties
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Child extends Parent {
    // More properties
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ConcreteParent")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class ConcreteParent extends Parent {
    // More properties
}
```

All the shared properties would be in `Parent` and `ConcreteParent` would have all the additional columns you wanted to put in the parent table.

If you wanted to instead have a parent table that doesn't have any different properties from the child table and the child table might have more properties, you could still use this approach.

This being said, take a look at the answers to a similar question: [Hibernate: Change instance of base class to subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457095/hibernate-change-instance-of-base-class-to-subclass/7457178#7457178).

The thing is, your model is probably wrong if you are trying to use inheritance to add functionality to an existing thing. Inheritance is useful for discriminating between different things that share some common properties.